# Get Option/Flag on product added to cart

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

Well i have an observer that is executed when a product is added to cart using magento API V1/guest-carts/:quoteID/items. I want to set the product with some flag, as long as the product is in the quote.

Any idea how is the best way to approach this?

Thanks, appreciate it.